# Helper classes in Codeigniter - are they really bad and why?

Tags: codeigniter, helper

I am developing my system with helper classes and I see on several sources that say "Helper classes" are not recommended in object orientated programming.

If so, why are they considered bad?

How do they play in with the MVC framework of Codeigniter?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strength and weakness of the helpers is that they don't neatly fit into the MVC framework; they're more like glue than wood or steel framing. They can be convenient to use in several contexts and are well-suited for common, light tasks. If your helpers become more complex and start needing to interact with models and controllers, odds are you've got a questionable design that needs to be more carefully considered. Glue and duct tape may be useful, but you'll be hard-pressed to find a skyscraper made of them.

Comment: So if im just using Helpers for simple validation, and database queries you think thats ok?

Comment: Definitely not database queries, and probably not validation. I typically keep database interaction limited to my models, and validation in controllers. CodeIgniter has a great [validation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html), in addition to a basic [overview of MVC](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html). The MVC design pattern has taken me a while to use effectively, and I'd highly recommend that you keep reading/researching before you get too far into building your app.

Comment: I am using the validation class, is that not a helper class? Just like form_helper or database helper. Maybe I did not say it correctly sorry

Comment: Look more closely at the [CodeIgniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/), and notice what's under the "Class Reference" heading the the "Helper Reference" heading. The form helper class neatly configures and outputs form elements, while the form validation class integrates with a controller to handle much more dynamic and complicated actions. Again, put some time into studying the MVC pattern and all of this will make more sense.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering in documentation how I would visualize loading e.g. "session_class" would that be a generalisation, aggregation in UML class modelling. Thanks